# How to fix --warn-shared-textrel warning?

Tags: shared-libraries

When I try to build a shared lib then I the see warning message

> warning: shared library text segment is not shareable

When I set the flag `--no-warn-shared-textrel` then all is ok.

What is the reason of the warning message when the flag `--warn-shared-textrel` is set and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The usual fix for this is to make sure you're compiling with `-fPIC`. Shared libraries can't rely on position dependent code because of how the dynamic linker works.

More information here: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Introduction_to_Position_Independent_Code